# Why PDFTron PDFViewCtrl.Update() throws AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, pdftron

I'm using PDFTron PDF annotation library in my windows store app project. Sometimes when I tried to load previously done annotations (save as a separate file) into the PDFView Control it throws AccessViolationException.
Please help.

On my page this is the code:

```
await ImportAnnotations(param.Doc, agendaItem);
this.PDFViewCtrl.Update(); //this is where the exception throws
```

This is ImportAnnotations function.

```
private async Task<PDFDoc> ImportAnnotations(PDFDoc doc, AgendaItem GlobalSelectdAgendaItem)
    {
        try
        {
            if (doc != null && GlobalSelectdAgendaItem != null)
            {
                StorageFolder documentsFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, Global.UserId.ToString(), ApplicationConstants.PDF));
                string annotationFileName = GlobalSelectdAgendaItem.ID + "_" + Global.UserId.ToString() + "_" + GlobalSelectdAgendaItem.VersionId + ".xfdf";

                // load XFDF annotations
                var anntotationFile = await documentsFolder.TryGetItemAsync(annotationFileName) as IStorageFile;
                FDFDoc fdfDoc = null;
                if (anntotationFile != null)
                {
                    fdfDoc = await FDFDoc.CreateFromXFDFAsync(Path.Combine(documentsFolder.Path, annotationFileName));
                }
                else
                {
                    return doc;
                }

                // load PDF with which to merge the annotations
                doc.InitSecurityHandler();

                // merge in the annotations
                doc.FDFMerge(fdfDoc);
                doc.RefreshFieldAppearances();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: what is the exception call stack?

Comment: Msg: {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Comment: This is the exception message, not the call stack.

Comment: Stacktrace:    at pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl.Update()
   at com.IronOne.BoardPACWinApp.View.Page.NewsAndShardDocsPage.<LoadPaperCommon>d__4d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object stateMachine)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying the document while it is being rendered in a background thread. Writing to shared data across threads, while also reading them, can cause random errors as you encountered.

You need to start and finish your ImportAnnotations function with `this.PDFViewCtrl.DocLock(true)` and `this.PDFViewCtrl.DocUnlock()`

[See this forum post for more details on this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/pDZsqrjCEdg)